# reading and writing into Microsoft access database through python

Tags: python, database, ms-access

Trying to read into a table in my database and grab data from the sheet row by row by column (in python)

then i need to write in my sheet as well. i have multiple tables in my database and i only want to read and write into one.

How do I read and write in access through python? someone said pypyodbc is a good use but i'm not so sure.

```
import pypyodbc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `pypyodbc`? What problems do you encounter with it?

Comment: i don't know how to do so @Nikita